# Uniformization Theorem Curvature on a Riemann sphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Given a Riemann surface $X$ and a conformal metric $\lambda(z)^{2} dz d\bar{z}, \lambda(z) > 0$ on it. The curvature of $X$ is defined to be $K = -\Delta \text{log}\lambda$ according to [https://www.math.wichita.edu/~ryan/teaching/M829F/syllabus/Jost-book/JJ_ch2.pdf](https://www.math.wichita.edu/%7Eryan/teaching/M829F/syllabus/Jost-book/JJ_ch2.pdf). This seems to be exactly the definition of scalar curvature for a Kahler manifold. Then is the uniformization thereom which states that every Riemann surface admits a conformally related metric of constant curvature referring to the scalar curvature? Isn't the uniformization then a direct consequence of the Yamabe problem?

Comment: Sure, but it’s a little easier to prove the uniformization theorem  than to solve the Yamabe problem. The former is one reason why people thought the latter might have a solution.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon This is a really clever comment. Would you mind that I quote it in an edit of my answer?

Comment: @Didier I don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ric}{Ric}
\DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{trace}
\DeclareMathOperator{\scal}{Scal}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rm}{Rm}$
In real dimension $2$, the scalar curvature is twice the sectional curvature.
Indeed, if $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is an orthonormal frame, then
\begin{align}
\ric(e_1,e_1) &= \rm(e_1,e_1,e_1,e_1) + \rm(e_1,e_2,e_1,e_2) = 0+ \sec(e_1,e_2) = \sec(e_1,e_2),\\
\ric(e_1,e_2) &= \rm(e_1,e_1,e_2,e_1) + \rm(e_1,e_2,e_2,e_2) = 0 + 0 = 0,\\
\ric(e_2,e_2) &= \rm(e_2,e_1,e_2,e_1) + \rm(e_2,e_2,e_2,e_2) = \sec(e_2,e_1) + 0= \sec(e_1,e_2).
\end{align}
(Note that I use the convention $\sec(X,Y) = \rm(X,Y,X,Y)=g(R(X,Y)X,Y)$ for orthonormal vector fields and $\ric(X,Y) =\trace\left(Z\mapsto R(X,Z)Y\right)$.)

Hence, we have $\ric = \sec \cdot g$.
Tracing this equality gives
$$
\scal = 2 \sec.
$$
It follows that the sectional curvature is constant if and only if the scalar curvature is constant.
Therefore, in dimension $2$, the Yamabe problem for $(M,g)$ is equivalent to finding a metric of constant sectional curvature in the conformal class $[g]$, which solves the uniformization problem.

However, as it is mentioned by @GunnarÞórMagnússon in the comment section, the uniformization problem is much easier to solve than the Yamabe problem. The fact that the uniformization Theorem was true is a main motivation that lead people to think that the Yamabe problem would be solvable.

Comment: Thank you for answering. A slightly irrelevant question about the uniformization theorem: There are more than 1 conformal structure on the unit disk, but the statement does not specify which conformal structure it is taking about, why?

Comment: @Adam Up to biholomorphisms, the uniformization Theorem tells you that there is exactly two conformal structures on the disk (the usual, and the one obtained by pulling back the conformal structure of the plane by a diffeomorphism). When talking about "the disk", we usually refer to the first one.